# After installing updates to a fresh install of 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04, my computer does not reboot.

Tags: updates, reboot

I freshly installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on my computer with a dual boot of Windows 7.

After installation it asks me to reboot. I do that and, after it reboots, the update manager automatically pops up and asks me to update around 140 things.

The update goes fine and, after it completes, it asks me to reboot.

This time when I reboot, the screen gets stuck at the Ubuntu start screen (The one with Ubuntu written with 5 dots below it) and doesn't do anything for hours.

What should I do?

Comment: Not sure if you are notified when someone answers a question, so adding a comment just to make sure you are notified.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you can successfully install Ubuntu 12.04 and that immediately after the install it boots with no problem? Is it only after you apply the pending updates that can no longer boot?

If that is what is happening then you can begin by attempting to isolate the problem.

Here is one way to try doing that.

Since Update Manager is asking you to reboot, I am guessing that one of the updates you applied was probably to install a new kernel. So ...

- Try only installing just the latest kernel instead of all 140 or so
  updates.
- Reboot to see if you reproduce the problem.
- If your problem does not repeat, try applying more updates and rebooting until you
  either reproduce the problem or you have applied all the updates.
- Edit your question and add a description of what you did and what
  happened.